# Dark borders in cv2.blur

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pygame, pygame-surface

I have this code on python that I use as a Bloom effect on my game, but I've noticed that it has this weird black shadow around the particles

[image: Effect in White Background]
[image: Effect in Grey Background]

The effect looks like this ^

as you can see, there is some shadows on the particles, on white background it's obvious, while in grey is subtle

I would like to know if there is a way to remove/reduce this weird effect

This is the code for the bloom (where the shadows are coming from):

```py
def Bloom(canvas: pygame.Surface):
    size = canvas.get_size()
    canvas_color = pygame.surfarray.array2d(canvas)
    canvas_rgba = canvas_color.view(dtype=np.uint8).reshape((*canvas_color.shape, 4))

    newCanvas = pygame.Surface(size, pygame.SRCALPHA)


    cv2.blur(canvas_rgba, ksize=(9, 9), dst=canvas_rgba)

    
    pygame.surfarray.blit_array(newCanvas, canvas_color)

    return newCanvas
```

Any help would be great :3

Edit: Removed the image with black background (no reason to be there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the "bloom" algorithm, but with the way you `blit` the surface to the target.
Not just the alpha channel is blurred, also the color channels are blurred. Therefore you have to [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the *Surface* with the special flag `BLEND_PREMULTIPLIED`:

```py
bloom_surf = Bloom(source_surf)
screen.blit(bloom_surf, (x, y), pygame.BLEND_PREMULTIPLIED)
```

It is also possible to cancel this effect in the `Bloom` function by dividing the color channels by the alpha channel:

```
r' = r / a
g' = g / a
b' = b / a
a' = a
```

Each color channel is coded in a byte in the range [0, 255]. That makes the conversion a little trickier:

```py
def BloomNoPremultipliedAlpha(canvas: pygame.Surface):
    size = canvas.get_size()
    canvas_color = pygame.surfarray.array2d(canvas)
    canvas_rgba = canvas_color.view(dtype=np.uint8).reshape((*canvas_color.shape, 4))
    newCanvas = pygame.Surface(size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    cv2.blur(canvas_rgba, ksize=(25, 25), dst=canvas_rgba)

    canvas_rgba[:,:,0:3] = canvas_rgba[:,:,0:3] * 255.0 / canvas_rgba[:,:,[3,3,3]]

    pygame.surfarray.blit_array(newCanvas, canvas_color)
    return newCanvas
```

---

See the following minimal example that demonstrates the difference:

[image]
left: `Bloom`; center: `Bloom` + `BLEND_PREMULTIPLIED`; right: `BloomNoPremultipliedAlpha`

```py
import pygame, cv2 
import numpy as np

def Bloom(canvas: pygame.Surface):
    size = canvas.get_size()
    canvas_color = pygame.surfarray.array2d(canvas)
    canvas_rgba = canvas_color.view(dtype=np.uint8).reshape((*canvas_color.shape, 4))
    newCanvas = pygame.Surface(size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    cv2.blur(canvas_rgba, ksize=(25, 25), dst=canvas_rgba)
    pygame.surfarray.blit_array(newCanvas, canvas_color)
    return newCanvas

def BloomNoPremultipliedAlpha(canvas: pygame.Surface):
    size = canvas.get_size()
    canvas_color = pygame.surfarray.array2d(canvas)
    canvas_rgba = canvas_color.view(dtype=np.uint8).reshape((*canvas_color.shape, 4))
    newCanvas = pygame.Surface(size, pygame.SRCALPHA)
    cv2.blur(canvas_rgba, ksize=(25, 25), dst=canvas_rgba)

    canvas_rgba[:,:,0:3] = canvas_rgba[:,:,0:3] * 255.0 / canvas_rgba[:,:,[3,3,3]]

    pygame.surfarray.blit_array(newCanvas, canvas_color)
    return newCanvas

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 100, *window.get_size(), (160, 160, 160), (96, 96, 96)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
[pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect) for rect, color in tiles]

surface = pygame.Surface((250, 250), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(surface, (255, 255, 255), surface.get_rect().center, 100)
surface1 = Bloom(surface)
surface2 = Bloom(surface)
surface3 = BloomNoPremultipliedAlpha(surface)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    window.blit(surface1, surface1.get_rect(center = (150, 150)))
    window.blit(surface2, surface2.get_rect(center = (400, 150)), special_flags = pygame.BLEND_PREMULTIPLIED)
    window.blit(surface3, surface1.get_rect(center = (650, 150)))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: that works great, thanks again, you helped me so much that I might put your name on the credits of my game :v